# What is the difference between `void operator=(T&&)` and `T& operator=(T&&)`?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value, assignment-operator

```cpp
class base 
{
public:
    base(const base&) = delete;
    base()
    {
        cout << "construct" << endl;
    }
    ~base() 
    {
        cout << "destruct" << endl;
    }

    int a;
    int b;

    /* The difference explanation I desired is here */
    void operator=(base&& other)  
    // base& operator=(base&& other) // this needs to collaborate with "return *this" 
    {
        this->a = other.a;
        this->b = other.b;
        // return *this;
    }

    /* Not here */
    base& operator=(base& other) = delete;
};
```

What is the difference between the two versions of `operator=(T&&)`? They seem both work to me. However, as class member function, the website recommand `base& operator=(T&&)` version.

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question. I recommend posting the second half as a separate question.

Comment: The difference between the two overloads shown is not primarily in what they return, but in what they take as a parameter. The one taking `base&& other` - an rvalue reference - is a move-assignment operator. The one taking `base& other` - an lvalue reference - is a copy-assignment operator. The move-assignment operator could - and usually does - return `base&` as well, there's no good reason to make it `void`

Comment: The usage of the two is different.    The copy assignment form (if not deleted) that returns `base &`  can be chained,  e.g. `x = y = z` where `x`, `y`, and `z` are all of type `base`.   The move assignment that returns `void` cannot be chained.    The net effect having a move assignment that return `void` and a deleted copy assignment is that only assignments with temporaries as rvalues are allowed, and no chaining is permitted.

Comment: An assignment operator can return whatever makes sense, including `void`.  Expectations are that it returns a reference to the object itself, but that's not a requirement.  There may be good reasons to "challenge the status quo" for some classes, or even as a team's standard policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one case, `a=b=c` works.  In the other, it does not.

That is it.

Traditionally, `a=b=c` does `b=c` then assigns the result to `a`.  If your `operator=` returns `void`, it instead fails to compile.